# Lightning bolt symbol without arrow at tip in LaTeX? (Unicode U+26A1)

Tags: symbols

I'd like to find a ⚡ symbol for TeX. When I try to draw something like it in Detexify, I get similar symbols, but they have a an arrow at the south end of the lightning bolt, unlike Unicode U+26A1 (which is ⚡). Are there any packages that implement such a lightning bolt?

Comment: Can you use xelatex or lualatex?

Comment: @DavidPurton No, sorry, I think I have to use latex!

Comment: With U+26A1 one refers to an “abstract character”; the graphic realization (the “glyph”) is a free choice by the font designer. What you see here is the particular realization in the font used by the browser when requested to represent U+26A1 and different people may see different glyphs, maybe with the arrow tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution with TikZ. The drawn symbol `\Lightning` has the height of a `H`. It has an optional argument to set some parameters like the fill and drawing colors. Also LaTeX's `\newcommand` makes macros with an optional argument robust.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\Lightning}[1][]{%
  \tikz[
    x=.55 * height("H"),  % symbol width
    y=height("H"),  % symbol height
    baseline=(current bounding box.south),
    line width=.02 * height("H"),
    line join=bevel,
  ]
  \filldraw[{#1}]
    (-.5, -.5) -- (.4, -.03) -- (-.1, .06) --
    (.5, .5) -- (-.4, .03) -- (.1, -.06) --
    cycle
    % side bearings
    (-.5 - .08, 0)
    (.5 + .08, 0)
  ;%
}

% Test
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
\begin{document}
  \fbox{\Lightning[fill=red, draw=blue]}%
  \Lightning
  \Lightning[fill=yellow, line join=round, xscale=1.25]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]